# sphinx search installed under root, how can i change owner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

i followed this tutorial:

> http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/install-sphinxsearch-205-in-ubuntu-1204-server

and installed sphinx on ubuntu 12 on ec2, the problem is that my rails app is running under a user called "ubuntu" and in my

> searchd.log

file i see warnings that it can't access the *.spl files.

```
FATAL: failed to open     /home/ubuntu/sites/app/shared/db/sphinx/production/group.tmp.spl: Permission denied,   will not index. Try --rotate option.
```

how can i change it so all of sphinx will run under ubuntu user and not root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may come at the beginning (in the tutorial) with `sudo su`, you are logging as root; you should install in EC2 with sudo, only.

I installed Sphinx in a EC2 like 1 and a half year ago, and I never used `sudo su`. I recommend you to uninstall Sphinx and install it again:

1. Get the tar
2. Configure the source code: `./configure –prefix=/usr/local`
3. Run: `make`
4. Run: `sudo make install`

Also, you should try Sunspot with Solr (I moved from Sphinx to Solr, it's better in my opinion for many reasons, there are many benchmarks). Hope it helps.

Comment: i ended up uninstalling and installing again like u said and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Installing Sphinx with root is fine, but you need to make sure you run all Thinking Sphinx rake tasks as the `ubuntu` user.

I would recommend stopping your Sphinx daemon (if it's running), then delete the index files, then run the `ts:rebuild` rake task via the `ubuntu` user to ensure the new index files and daemon are set up with the correct permissions.

Comment: thanks for the answer. thinking sphinx is running with my ubuntu user (i think, otherwise it could of access those index files)
how do i check if the sphinx deamon is running? (sorry for the noob question) and i will try your solution later today. thanks

Comment: run `ps aux | grep searchd` and if there's a searchd process, that's Sphinx. It should also tell you which user that process is being run through.

Comment: deleted all index files. killed the process, then ran ts:rebuild is started the process. i ran ts:reindex and then it gave the same permission denied error, and the entire folder is filled again with files that belong to the root user

Comment: Are you sure you're running ts:rebuild with the ubuntu user?

Comment: yes sure about it. i only connect to the server with the ubuntu user